# Difference of two identical data points in model in a Vue.js component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In a Vue component, the data property `items` (Array) exist. During application usage `item`s are added to this list, and `item` is an object.

```js
Vue.component('list-of-people', {
  template: '<ul>\
    <li v-for="person in ppl">\
      {{person.name}} <button v-on:click="remove(person)">X</button>\
    </li>\
  </ul>\
  <button v-on:click="addJoe">Add Joe, 12</button>',
  props: ['ppl'],
  methods: {
    addJoe: function() {
      this.$emit('add-a-joe', { name: 'joe', age: 12 });
    },
    remove: function(person) {
      this.$emit('remove-person', person);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: []
  },
  methods: {
    addPerson: function(person) {
      this.items.push(person);
    },
    removePerson: function(person) {
      //... How do I handle this?
    }
  }
 });
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <list-of-people v-bind:ppl="items"
                  v-on:add-a-joe="addPerson"
                  v-on:remove-person="removePerson"></list-of-people>
</div>
```

In a case where `item` is added once, and then another `item` with the same value is added to `items`, there will be two objects in the `items` array with the same properties and the same values (in this case, there are two joe who are both 12 years old).

Is there a way for me to remove one of them by supplying the `item` I wish to remove?

For instance, if I click the "Add Joe, 12" button a few times, then click on the X next to one of the Joes, I'll emit an event up the line with the object of joe that I want to remove from the data model. How can I make sure Vue removes the first joe from the list, instead of any joe that may be in the list?

Will Vue add some ID to data in it's models to keep track of identical data entries? How's this generally handled?

Comment: Sorry for the example - it doesn't run, but it's just a proof of concept.

Comment: Disclaimer: Not sure if I understood your problem correctly.

Data is manipulated via (vue-agnostic) javascript. Something like `this.items.indexOf(person)` will return (only) the first index, which you can then use to remove the element from the array. That should work perfectly fine.
However, if you always render in that particular order you could also use `v-for=(person, i) in ppl` and `v-on:click="removePerson(i)"`.

Comment: In my case, it's pretty safe to say that the order in `items` will remain the same. So including the index sounds like a viable approach for me (thanks). However if the order may change and I do not want to simply find the _first_ index, I would then have to add an ID manually? Something like `"added-at": timestamp`, in each item would suffice. Just to make sure that I'm removing the correct person?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you're already using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) you could use the [uniqueId](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqueId) function to generate IDs.